# Excel VBA: How to access data in all the cells of a column using a loop and assign that data to a string variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to learn: 
I have a column (column 'F') of flags('1' for Yes and '0' for No). I would like to loop through each cell in the column and if the flag in that cell is a '1', I would like to use a string variable to hold the data in the other cells on that row adjacent to the cell containing the '1' Flag.

This is so I can take these string to customize the email with these string and send many emails to different users using the email Id's in column 'C'. 
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY3QQ.png)
Here is my code so Far:

```
Sub Sendmail()
    Dim answer As String
    Dim SubmitLink_BorrowerName As String
    Dim SubmitLink_BookName As String
    Dim SubmitLink_CheckoutDate As String
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set KeyCells = Range("F2:F10") 'Range of 'Y/N' for whole column
    SubmitLink_BorrowerName = Range("A2").Value  'SubmitLink contains content of cell B1
    SubmitLink_BookName = Range("B2").Value  'SubmitLink contains content of cell B1
    SubmitLink_CheckoutDate = Range("D2").Value  'SubmitLink contains content of cell B1
    answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to save this change. An Email will be sent to the User", vbYesNo, "Save the change")

    If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
    If answer = vbYes Then
        For i = 2 To 20
        If Cells(i, 6).Value = 1 And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6).Value) Then
            Cells(i, 6).Font.Color = vbBlue


        'Open Outlook
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        'Add recipient
        newmsg.Recipients.Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
        'Add subject
        newmsg.Subject = "Book: " & SubmitLink_BookName & " overdue" 'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value
        'Add body
        newmsg.Body = "Dear " & SubmitLink_BorrowerName & "," & vbLf & vbLf & "This is a friendly reminder that Book: " & SubmitLink_BookName & " borrowed on " & SubmitLink_CheckoutDate & " has not yet been returned to the PC team." & vbLf & vbLf & "Kindly return this book to the Book shelf" & vbLf & "Regards, " & vbLf & vbLf & "Admin"

        'Display
        newmsg.Display
        newmsg.Send
        MsgBox "Modification confirmd", , "Confirmation"


        End If
    End If



End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add Next i.**strong text**

```
If answer = vbYes Then
    For i = 2 To 20
    If Cells(i, 6).Value = 1 And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6).Value) Then
        Cells(i, 6).Font.Color = vbBlue


    'Open Outlook
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    'Add recipient
    newmsg.Recipients.Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Value
    'Add subject
    newmsg.Subject = "Book: " & SubmitLink_BookName & " overdue" 'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value
    'Add body
    newmsg.Body = "Dear " & SubmitLink_BorrowerName & "," & vbLf & vbLf & "This is a friendly reminder that Book: " & SubmitLink_BookName & " borrowed on " & SubmitLink_CheckoutDate & " has not yet been returned to the PC team." & vbLf & vbLf & "Kindly return this book to the Book shelf" & vbLf & "Regards, " & vbLf & vbLf & "Admin"

    'Display
    newmsg.Display
    newmsg.Send
    MsgBox "Modification confirmd", , "Confirmation"


    End If
 Next i

End If
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I also need to know something else:

Comment: I have a column ‘F’ called ‘Email[Y/N]- see image. If there is a ‘1’ on any row in that column, then an email should be sent to the name mentioned in column ‘A’ by using their email id in column ‘C’ FROM THAT SAME ROW. In my VBA code, I have stored these ‘1’s and ‘0’s in ‘KeyCells’ hopefully correctly? Right now, the SubmitLink_BorrowerName, SubmitLink_BookName and SubmitLink_CheckoutDate are static variables and do not change depending on the row that has the ‘1’ in column ‘F’. I need to change it so that it takes the name, etc depending on the appropriate row.

Comment: Is there a way, I can move these variables inside the loop?How can I alter the A2 so that the cell changes according to the row but the column is the same in: SubmitLink_BorrowerName = Range("A2").Value